# Changing password of farm account from Central Adminstration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, central-administration, farm-admin

I have a single server farm and I want to change farm admin password. It is being used to run different services such as timer job, central admin, SQL Server, Search etc.

Plus it is also being used in application pools in IIS.

My question is if I change its password from central administration, will it automatically update all services and application pools?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will automatically update the password everywhere it used except the SQL server's services. I would recommend following as per my experience.

1. Change the Farm admin account password in AD
2. In the Central admin on change password page use the option " Use Existing password"
3. Now update the SQL Server Service account.SharePoint will not update it automatically
4. DO IISreset and recycle SharePoint timer service to verfiy

I had issues when i tried to change the password from SharePoint to AD.

Comment: Yes, this will work for all services using a Managed Account! But for SQL Server you'll need to re-enter the password for the SQL Windows Service.

Comment: Good catch, i missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Frank,

Here are the steps you need to take to make sure accounts stay up to date when passwords change. You should be using managed accounts for this.

[Keep service and feature account passwords up-to-date in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262502.aspx)

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Jim